# Hidden text can be selected in IE despite style='display:none'

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

This appears to be an IE-specific 'feature'.  I tested using IE8. User [John H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729541/john-h) has contributing by confirming in IE6 and IE7.

I have some text that gets built into my page and from the beginning of the element's creation it has `style = "display: none;"`

I'm not using jQuery to hide the text and the text is not 'showing up'. Although, for further disclosure, I do access the element's contents using jQuery's `.html()` method.

However, if the user selects text *nearby* my `display:none` element and copies what has been selected, the hidden text gets included. Just as though it had been displaying normally.

The markup looks like this:

```
...
<td align="left">
    Text they should see
    <div id="whateverButUnique" style="display:none;">Value I want hidden</div>
    Some other text
</td>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zexC6/) where I can reproduce the issue using IE<9.

While this is not a serious concern for this particular application, it caught me off-guard and I wondered if this is a 'feature' or if I was doing something incorrectly.

Most of the [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536968/css-display-not-working) I've seen regarding `display:none` had their posters' content as visible. Again, my content is essentially invisible **until** selected, copied, and finally pasted.

Can I prevent Internet Explorer users from finding this content by copying / pasting? I realize they could see it in Developer Tools and by viewing the source.

**Update:** thanks to other user's comments, I have also tried applying the style of `visibility:hidden` and `z-index=-1`. User [John H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729541/john-h) has tried lots of other hiding attempts but IE is so far tenacious at allowing this feature to slip through. Thanks for all the great ideas!

**Update:** Thanks for asking [Heather Walters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1077783/heather-walters); the values that I need to use on the page are available server-side only but I then use them *after the page loads* to generate a link using extra processing from an outside program via jQuery/AJAX. So I build the page with the values hidden but included and then operate on those hidden values to build something useful with them.

Once I am done using them to build something useful, though, I now realize I could wipe them all out via jQuery and take an extra performance hit. The following code would accomplish this for everyone that has javascript enabled:

```
$("[id^=whateverButUnique]").html("");
```

With potentially hundreds of elements on the page this extra processing is not ideal.

[vega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297641/vega), I don't believe [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733679/displaynone-content-copied-to-clipboard-visible-when-pasted/1055701#1055701) would work for me because I have to build the page and my hidden content on the server side. They are all built in a server-side loop with potentially hundreds of other elements so I have the choice to either build it in place while the server is laying everything out in a table (with hidden element included) or loop through it a second time (painful) and try to force the elements to display:none somewhere less likely to be selected.

[Ohgodwhy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206267/ohgodwhy), I wanted to believe in your solution. In IE8, the hidden field didn't show up in notepad; however, I was able to copy the section and paste it into Microsoft Word. It was no longer hidden.

Another factor at work: this page is already pretty javascript heavy so I was hoping I could find a solution that would prevent IE from seeing the values without adding another pass through 100+ potential elements...but I might just have to.

**Update**: [Robin Maben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448232/robin-maben)'s suggestion looks like it will be a *great* workaround! His suggestion is to hide the values in the `data-x` custom HTML5 attribute. This appears to be working despite my (most likely) non HTML5 compliant page. Please up-vote his answer if you also consider it a valuable contribution.

**Update**: Confirmed. I have successfully implemented Maben's suggestion and therefore have been able to reduce the number of DOM look-ups -- one for every element on my page. I was already looping through all of the DIVs with items that I wanted to show, and now I can automatically access the data property at the same time. This looks like this in my implementation:

```
<div style="display:none" data-call-number="..." id="stackLocatorLinkFillUp...">...</div>
```

The ellipsis indicate unique-to-me operations going on. The id has a simple numerical indicator that increments one per record.

```
// Loop through all of the items on the page that start with my id
$("[id^=stackLocatorLinkFillUp]").each( function() {
    // ...
    // Grab the contents of the div
    var innerContent = $(this).html();
    // Extract the call number out of the data-call-number field
    var callNumPreEncoded = $(this).data("callNumber");
    // ...eventually...
    $(this).html(...).css("display","block");
});
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I recall having IE-specific problems trying to hide elements.  Have you tried using "visibility: hidden"?

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour for IE6, IE7 and IE8.  IE9 would behave as you would (hope) expect.  I'm going to guess they just treat it as a normal element in the document which allows it to be copied.  I have no idea if there's a way around it though.  I tried positioning the element off-screen but that didn't change anything.  Would be interesting if someone knows of a work-around.

Comment: Thanks @dbaseman; so far I have tried, display:none, visibility:hidden, and z-index=-1 but the text can still get copied into the buffer. @John H, thank you for your confirmation. It will be interesting!

Comment: No problem. :)  Just tried floating it to see if that'd take it out of the normal document flow, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: The size display and position of the element doesn't matter, it's being selected because when you select things in IE<9, you are selecting html and then pasting that html, with hidden elements. IE9 and other browsers properly remove those hidden elements from the selection. The only way to prevent it is to not have the hidden element in the dom.

Comment: Probably http://stackoverflow.com/a/1055701/297641 can help.

Comment: Okay. well in that case, change the Div to an `<input type="hidden"` and give it a `style="user-select:none"`. Pretty sure this is the intended functionality anyway. At least that's how I would secure text within a input box cross-browser. http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you including hidden text on your page?

Comment: @HeatherWalters, I updated the question to reflect this; Vega, that does look eerily familiar but I updated my question with my thoughts about it; Ohgodwhy, thank you for the idea but I found your idea copyable/pastable into MS Word. [Seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/zexC6/8/)

Comment: @KevinB: please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it as the correct one unless someone else is able to show a way to keep these elements un-selectable in IE<9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size display and position of the element doesn't matter, it's being selected because when you select things in IE<9, you are selecting html and then pasting that html, with hidden elements. IE9 and other browsers properly remove those hidden elements from the selection. The only way *i know of* to prevent it is to not have the hidden element in the dom.

Comment: Thank you Kevin for the succinct response; I believe you have answered the original question correctly and so I have counted this as the answer. However, for all those who might be in a similar situation and want an alternative when their div is not hidden from select/copy/paste in IE<9, check out @RobinMaben's post below. I now have one less div and therefore one less DOM look-up.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>Have you tried the **`visibility:collapse`** property?</strike>

If the "`Value I want hidden`" part is used purely for computational purposes, you should use the **"`data`" attribute.**

Like this

```
<div data-custom-value="1001">Visible value </div>
```

In jQuery, HTML data attributes are automatically available via the `data()` api.

You can do

`someElement.data('customValue')` to read a value.

and

`someElement.data('customValue', newValue)` to set a value.

Hope I analyzed your problem correctly.

Comment: Do you mean that I should set the style like so: `style='display:none; visibility:collapse'`? That did not resolve the issue of being selectable / copyable / pastable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have not experimented much with visibility up until now. Sadly it doesn't make it less available to users wanting to copy the text next to it (in IE<9).

Comment: Robin; thank you for your suggestion. Are you intimately familiar with when this can and/or shouldn't be used? I read [something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148432/how-to-add-a-certain-value-to-anchor-tag) seeming to indicate that this would / should only work _IF_ HTML5 is being used. It looks like it is working for me in the three main browsers. Should I trust what "seems to work" or are there any surprises to be aware of? (or is this my misunderstanding and putting data-blah automatically into my div means I'm implementing HTML5?)

Comment: @veeTrain: This post http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1453-Using-jQuery-With-Custom-XHTML-Attributes-And-Namespaces-To-Store-Data.htm  has a solution to your fears.

Comment: @veeTrain: Using the data attribute does not automatically tell the browser you're using HTML5. For that, you need to use the HTML5 doctype. Like this "<!DOCTYPE html>"

Comment: My DOCTYPE is not that currently; should I be leery then to rely on `data()` to retrieve what would be built into the DOM? The link didn't actually have an example of him using the data() property to get at the value but rather `jThis.attr( "bn:imdb" )`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10068/discussion-between-veetrain-and-robin-maben)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you use:

```
position: absolute; left: -10000px;
```

That will eliminate any potential IE problems.

Comment: I can still copy / paste the hidden text with your idea. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zexC6/5/).

Comment: I also could still see the text in my live environment via IE8 of course. Thanks for your suggestion