# Does too many hidden inputs affect the page rendering speed?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, performance

I'm at the point where I'll need to keep some data about my control in hidden fields. I'm using MVC 3 for the record. My worry is that I'll be using the hidden fields like a poor man's viewstate. In doing that, I feel that I'll be running the risk of causing the page to renderly slowly (or slower). An example of what I'm talking about is below.

So in short, will having a lot of hidden fields on a page cause the page to run/render slowly?

An example of what one row will look like:

```
<div>
    <div>1.</div>
    <div>
        Enter the measurements for the bridge legs (record from left to right, top, then bottom):
        (I am one of many rows in this form.)</div>
    <div><input type="text" id="1" name="leg" /><input type="hidden" id="1" name="dataid" value="101" />
        <input type="text" id="2" name="leg" /><input type="hidden" id="2" name="dataid" value="102" />
        <input type="text" id="3" name="leg" /><input type="hidden" id="3" name="dataid" value="103" />
        <input type="text" id="4" name="leg" /><input type="hidden" id="4" name="dataid" value="104" />
        <input type="text" id="5" name="leg" /><input type="hidden" id="5" name="dataid" value="105" />
        <input type="text" id="6" name="leg" /><input type="hidden" id="6" name="dataid" value="106" />
        <input type="text" id="7" name="leg" /><input type="hidden" id="7" name="dataid" value="107" />
        <input type="text" id="8" name="leg" /><input type="hidden" id="8" name="dataid" value="108" />
        <input type="text" id="9" name="leg" /><input type="hidden" id="9" name="dataid" value="109" />
        <input type="text" id="10" name="leg" /><input type="hidden" id="10" name="dataid" value="110" /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</div>
```

I will end up having a page that has 80 rows and each row having multiple controls. Given this situation am I overworrying or do I have a legitimate concern?

Comment: Having elements with the same `id` is invalid HTML.

Comment: I created I small(?) fiddle to test it:http://jsfiddle.net/zU5mN/

Comment: You may also want to think a little more on your UI. Do you have 80 visible rows with 10 input controls each one?

Comment: Well no, they will have multiple controls in each one. One row may have 1, another 2, another 4. Depends on what input is needed.

Comment: I guess based on the suggestions to avoid the hidden fields that the hidden fields will make the page slower.

Comment: Great question, but no one answered whether this would cause page rendering to slow down. Jury's still out.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid those extra hidden fields using custom attributes for your visible inputs

```
<input type="text" id="1" name="leg" data-id="101" />
```

Using jquery, you would get the `data-id` attribute like this

```
var id = $('#1').data('id');
```

As a side note and since you said that you have multiple rows, be sure you're not repeating your input ids.

Comment: But how would I return those data-ids to the controller? At this moment I'm not using jquery, just stock, out of the box MVC 3.

Comment: @dotnetN00b: you could use one hidden field for all inputs, you could use json format or any other format you like.

Comment: @dotnetN00b: also, I'd like to know how you use those values on the server. It's not clear for me how you set the value for your hidden fields and what you are using them for.

Comment: my database has a table which has: dataid, ctrlid, savedData, userid, enteredDate. The ctrlID is the id of the textboxes. The hidden input represents the dataId. There is another table that holds the text and controls for the row. This information is joined in the controller and laid out in the View.

Comment: You could also use a composited id containing both ids. Something like  `id = "ctrlid_dataid"` `id="1_101"` on server you just have to split the id to get both values.

Comment: The data-id looks good but I don't think there's a way to get that data back to the controller through just plain ol' MVC3. Is there?

Comment: @dotnetN00b: no, there is no built in method to get those attributes on the server. You need to add custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

I too would strongly suggest using the jQuery-HTML5 `data()` API.

You should be using it if these values are complementary data.

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129613/hidden-text-can-be-selected-in-ie-despite-style-displaynone/10130156#10130156) to this question.

As for passing it to the controller, you could pass it via Ajax, if that's an option you can try.

```
$.ajax({
  url : '/Controller/Action/',
  data : { param1 : 'Hello' }
});
```