# Number of hidden inputs in HTML doc affecting page rendering speed

Tags: html, performance, pagespeed

Does the number of `hidden` input fields in an HTML document affect the speed of page rendering in a browser? Yes or no? My guess is the answer is **no** since `hidden` fields aren't rendered at all. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm in a situation where I have a bunch of forms on the page, each decked out with up to 100 `hidden` input fields. Should I be concerned in terms of performance? I'm already trying to reduce this number for maintenance purposes, but I need to know the performance penalty (if any).

*Note: A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298446/does-too-many-hidden-inputs-affect-the-page-rendering-speed), but although people gave work-arounds, nobody addressed the actual performance-based question*

Comment: I doesn't know if the rendering speed is affected, but the loading speed on network is affected (mobile connections).

Comment: @SebastianBrosch: interesting observation. To be exact (and so we're on the same page), you're saying more data needs to be sent, thus this would affect network transfer. What about DOM processing, since each `hidden` field is a `DOMString`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rendering speed is affected on hidden `<input>` fields but only on a heavy amount of fields (> 500). But the loading speed of the website is more affected! You are loading unnecessary HTML elements. So this can be a factor on slow internet connections (like mobile internet).

I recommend to remove all HTML code you doesn't need to improve the loading speed. After this step you don't have to worry about the rendering speed.

---

I have now inspected and tested the behaviour in Google Chrome. I created different HTML files with a different amount of hidden `<input>` fields (0, 100, 1.000, 10.000). So I tracked some interesting factors (loading, rendering and painting speed) with the following result:

[image]

***Note:*** all numbers in ms - milliseconds

I used the following template with the different amount of hidden input fields on a local file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <input type="text"/>
      <input type="hidden"/> <!-- x times -->
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very pertinent. I think one strategy to use could be to pack all required fields into a single, concatenated `hidden` field, and then break it up into separate tokens on the server. This could help reduce the size of payload being sent over the network, and still be flexible enough.

Comment: @HassanBaig - updated the answer with some additional information.

Comment: That is just awesome

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't think it will effect the page rendering for 100 hidden input fields (maybe 0.005s slower, so small that is consider negligible).

The reason it is slower is because of the **extra html in the page** but not the hidden fields. To make my statement clearer is like adding 100 paragraph elements but I set each with an CSS `display:none;`.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Vincent. What about any effects on DOM processing, since each `hidden` field is a `DOMString`?

Comment: I think it depends on what JavaScript code you are using, if you are gonna do something that loops through the 100 hidden fields then I think it will be slower, but if you are targeting specifically using `document.getElementById("xxxxx")`. I don't think will be an issue.... Again I might be wrong.

Comment: Well I'm speaking from a purely HTML/CSS standpoint at the moment, no JS involved.

Comment: If just from HTML/CSS standpoint the hidden fields will be rendered, again it is so small that is negligible for just 100 hidden fields. You can open the developer tools in your browser and you can see all the hidden fields are rendered as well.

Comment: Fair enough. Moreover, what do you think about Sebastian's comment under the question - i.e. that network transfer would get bloated as well - which could be a factor on throttled mobile internet.