# Using POST to pass multiple values and filter DB

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the form

```
<form action="resultpage.php" method="POST" onSubmit="setValue()">
<button type="submit" class="button" id='send-value' name='storage' value=''>Klik hier voor de laptops</button>
```

First, I change the value of the submit button with .JS before it gets submitted:

```
let ram = "8GB";
let processor = "i5";
let graphcard = "2GB";
function setValue() {
     document.getElementById("send-value").value = ram;
}
```

then I look it up with PHP when received

```
$ramResult = $_POST['storage'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE ram = '$ramResult' ;";
```

But I want to be able to look up multiple values like where ram = 8gb and processor = i5 and graphcard = 2GB

I tried .JS :

```
function setValue() {
  document.getElementById("send-value").value = ram, graphcard, processor;
}
```

But that does not work, and even if it would work I would not be able to tell which values belong to `ram, graphcard, processor;`

I'm trying to figure out a way to let .JS do the following:

```
function setValue() {
  document.getElementById("send-value").value = "ram":ram, "graphcard":graphcard, "processor": processor;
}
```

So that I can do something in PHP like

```
$allResult = $_POST['storage'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE ram = '$allResult.ram' AND graphcard = 'allResult.graphcard' AND processor = 'allResult.processor';";
```

that PHP would probably also not work.. Will need to figure that out also.

----EDIT
So as a newbie I decided to create a newbie solution. Instead of creating a lot of hidden inputs, .JS created the hidden inputs with the values only in the area needed (kind of dynamic which is a victory for me).

```
<form id="post-form" action="resultpage.php" method="POST" onSubmit="setValue()">
<button type="submit" class="button">Klik hier voor de laptops</button>
</form>
```

the .JS:

```
function setValue() {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var att = document.createAttribute("name"); 
  att.value = "ram";
  var att2 = document.createAttribute("value"); 
  att2.value = ram;
  input.setAttributeNode(att);
  input.setAttributeNode(att2);
  document.getElementById("post-form").appendChild(input);
}
```

I will have to repeat this in .JS for all the inputs needed and only call that script when needed in order to relieve the site a bit from processing.

Comment: Where do you _get_ those values you want to search for in the first place? _“ram = 8gb and processor = i5 and graphcard = 2GB”_ - are these supposed to be static / pre-defined, or are they supposed user input? If the latter - where does that input happen in the first place?

Comment: Why don't you use multiple inputs to enter those details?

Comment: @04FS These are predefined. I've got a couple  of buttons and each button has it's own values predefined. e.g. button 2, if pressed means u want ram 8GB, processor i5, etc.

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar I've got approx 27 buttons, if I add 5/6 inputs for each button that would mess up the html file.

Comment: You can use dropdown instead of multiple buttons

Comment: You can send only text values, not complex data structures. Encoding the data you have into JSON probably makes the most sense here.

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar Design if the site should be buttons, not dropdown I'm afraid

Comment: @04FS Thanks, any search key I can use to look up how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("send-value").value = 'ram:'+ram + ',graphcard:'+graphcard + ',processor:'+processor;
```

This will give you result something like this in POST

```
ram:8GB,graphcard:2GB,processor:i5
```

Now in PHP you can do

```
$convertToarray = explode(',', $_POST['storage']);

for($i=0; $i < count($convertToarray ); $i++){
    $key_value = explode(':', $convertToarray [$i]);
    $end_array[$key_value [0]] = $key_value [1];
}

$sql = "select * FROM laptops WHERE ram = '".$end_array['ram']."' AND graphcard = '".$end_array['graphcard']."' AND processor = '".$end_array['processor']."'";
```

Comment: I think it's not reading the apostrophe correctly, it's reading the "AND" as a string which makes it fail.

Comment: It's not giving an error, it's just not working when the site is loaded. But I think the issue is with the $sql = line. "AND" is being read as a string. e.g. "FROM" and "WHERE" are in the color red in my code editor because it recognizes it's sql. "AND" is not in red so is not being recognized as sql.

Answer (score -1):

You sent just one input use hidden input for post multiple value like:
**HTML/JS**

```
<input type="hidden" id="ram"  value="">
<input type="hidden" id="graphcard"  value="">
<input type="hidden" id="processor"  value="">
function setValue() {
document.getElementById("ram").value = ram;
document.getElementById("graphcard").value = graphcard;
document.getElementById("processor").value = processor;
}
```

**PHP**

```
$ram= $_POST['ram'];
$graphcard= $_POST['graphcard'];
$processor= $_POST['processor'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE ram = '$ram' AND graphcard = '$graphcard' AND processor = '$processor';";
```

If value is pre-defined just input form and use normal variable:

```
$ram= '8gb';
$graphcard= 'nvidia';
$processor= 'i9';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE ram = '$ram' AND graphcard = '$graphcard' AND processor = '$processor';";
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I've also thought of that. But because I've got approx 27 buttons, adding 5-6 hidden inputs would mess up the html file. If there's no other way I would go for this way but was trying to dry it up

Comment: Please don't post answers with OLD FASHIONED MYSQL Query. Use Prepared Statements.

Comment: @AmanjotKaur true, but I'm trying to get it working first. then I would change it to prepared statements :)

Comment: If you don't want to create multiple hidden fields, you can go with sessions. Create a session array with all the default values and then update as soon as the user clicks the buttons via ajax. And in Queries, you can check values from session.

Comment: @number42 if you see that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132425/number-of-hidden-inputs-in-html-doc-affecting-page-rendering-speed) about rendering time, you can add much hidden input.

Comment: I think a way that I can test is letting .JS creating HTML inputs with the values at submit. Hopefully that gets created in time before the POST is send.