# Creating a web page with images, but replace the images with text when copy and pasted

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML, which consists of messages as well as emoticons. An emoticon is written as follows:

```
<img src='client/img/tongueout.gif'>
```

But when I copy and paste it into something else, the emoticons are removed, and I lose the expression. Instead, I'd like to have a :P added into the text in place of the image. I tried using alt text, which didn't work. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: "But when I copy and paste it into something else, the emoticons are removed" What do you mean?

Comment: The 'alt' attribute is always required with **img** tag in HTML, it's not an option.

Comment: So I'm stupid and can't add an alt tag, apparently. Any way to close this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to place your alternate text beside the emoji icon, but hide it somehow by use of special css styles.

Styles like as `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` will not work as they are removed from text when you copy-paste the web page! you should use some css like as `clip: rect(0,0,0,0)` or `opacity:0` for this purpose as following demo:

```css
img.emoji { width:20px; height:20px; }

.emojiText {
  display: inline-block; 
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<p>Copy-Paste the following line into a text editor, <br/>
  you should see ":D)" instead of the image icon:</p>

<div>First word, 
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/220px-SNice.svg.png" class="emoji">
<span class="emojiText">:D)</span>, Second Word</div>
```

Comment: did you test it? whats your feedback?

Comment: There was a time when the `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` did work but that no longer seems to be the case.  My answer was based on info from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733679/displaynone-content-copied-to-clipboard-visible-when-pasted and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2974910/when-copying-text-from-webpage,-hidden-text-may-be-copied-too